# PostgreSQL UPDATE issue with NULL values

Tags: postgresql

Hopefully just a quick question. I have a simple performance-related question. Let's say I have a two table which is always connected each other. One of them having a trigger that ready to update reader column. But it takes a ages to update because of row number and i think so its about the wrong configuration. My postgresql query is like:  (Actually its also trigger)

```sql
UPDATE
    "libraryusers"
SET
    "reader" = (
        SELECT
            "username"
        FROM
            "userlist" i
        WHERE
                i."userneame" = "userlist"."usernames"
            AND i."date" >= "libraryusers"."date"
        ORDER BY
            i."date"
        LIMIT 1
    );
```

My question is how do i update only (null) rows ?  I want to update the record of a only reader cell null user only. But the update trigger fires for all the users. With that query in 1m+ rows it takes a around 15~20sec now.  I'd try something with where clause:

```sql
UPDATE 
    "libraryusers" 
SET
    "reader" = (
        SELECT
            "username"
        FROM
            "userlist" i 
        WHERE 
                "libraryusers"."reader" IS NULL 
            AND i."userneame" = "userlist"."usernames"
            AND i."date" >= "libraryusers"."date"
        ORDER BY
            i."date"
        LIMIT 1
    );
```

But i think so i missed something important here. I really appreciate if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The trigger is on which table? The code for the trigger and trigger function is? Not sure which field you are testing for NULL?

Comment: Should'nt you use `"reader" IN (` instead `"reader" = (` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update statements take their own WHERE clause to decide which rows get updated.  That is where the condition belongs:

```
UPDATE 
    "libraryusers" 
SET
    "reader" = (...)
WHERE "reader" is null
```